# Adaptive design in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, responsive-design, media-queries

I'm making an adaptive design version of my app. And I have problems with IE  (surprisingly, isn't it?=)
I have the following style code:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
    .flex-string{
         flex-wrap:wrap;
         flex-direction:column-reverse;
    }
    .flex-string > div{
         width:100%;
    }
}
```

This code work well in all browsers, but in IE 11 the app always renders like the page width is less than 1200 px; rerendering take place when I opening the developer console or resizing the window. Does somebody know how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the "Zoom Level" in Internet Explorer is set at 100%.